# How how to change spacemacs from helm to ivy?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

During the initial setup spacemacs asked, "What type of completion framework do you want?" and I selected "helm".

Now I want to use ivy instead.
How to change spacemacs from helm to ivy?
There are 16 occurrences of "helm" in my ~/.spacemacs file.

I added "spacemacs-ivy" at top of ~/.spacemacs file and restarted, but that didn't work
 as described in https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/407q2c/ivy_is_now_available_in_spacemacs/ .
On restart emacs said "Spacemacs encountered an error while loading your '.spacemacs' file."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no .spacemacs file, Spacemacs asks some questions and creates a new .spacemacs file.

I reinstalled spacemacs by deleting .spacemacs file and then restarting emacs.
I answered the questions like this:

```
What is your preferred editing style? vim
What distribution of spacemacs would you like to start with? spacemacs
What type of completion framework do you want? ivy
```

Now ivy is installed.

Answer (score 9):

I just put `ivy` in `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` along with other layer names in configuration file and everything seems to work.

And I don't know if anything should be put at the "top" of `.spacemacs`.